# Postgres pgadmin4 error: Unable to connect to server: timeout expired on docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-toolbox

I'm running a dockerised django app with db settings: [docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktaxl.png)

I want to connect the db to pgadmin4, for that created a pgadmin4 container using

```
docker run -p 5555:80 --name pgadmin -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL='postgresdb' -e
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD='password' dpage/pgadmin4;
```

and logged in on chrome with `<docker-machine ip>:5555`
Initiated a new server there with

- Host name/address: <ip of running db service> (attained using `docker inspect` on the running db container)
- port: 5432 (which is shown as the default port open for db service)

When trying to connect its delays for a second and shows this timeout error:  "Unable to connect to server: timeout expired on docker"

Any workaround for this issue.

Although, I can connect using terminal with `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`, is there any way I can connect using pgadmin4. I'm new to both docker and PostgreSQL.

(to check the issue, I've closed the django app and, initiated another postgres container manually using, `docker run --name local-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=incorrect -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine`and try to connect to pgadmin4 using same way it connects successfully, but with the django server it fails..)